# C++ File of 300 numbers not completely reading into an array. First 4 numbers are not included

Tags: c++

I can read in the data but then it doesn't include the first four. Expanding the array to 304 adds random numbers. Starting at i=-3 starts at the first number but immediately crashes the program. What to do?

```
int main(){
   ifstream inFile;
   inFile.open("number.txt");

   if(inFile.fail()){
      cerr << "Error" << endl;
      exit(1);
   }
   int array[300];
   for(int i=0;i<300;i++){
      inFile >> array[i];
      cout << array[i] << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should open it in binary mode if you want to read non-textual data

Comment: You should probably upload the first few numbers of the file. And as the other user said, you have to tell us if the file is in binary or regular text.

Comment: You'll always get a crash if you write `foo[-1]` or any other negative number.

Comment: Provide a representative example of the input file .... at minimum the first FIVE lots of data (assuming sixth and subsequent lots of data are in the same format as the fifth).

Comment: @JackDeeth it's not true, actually everything could happend, not only crash.

Comment: @coredump ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H you'll get **undefined behaviour**. I stand corrected. And you may get a compiler warning if you're lucky.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that everything was working fine. What was wrong: the run window was too small so I changed its size by right clicking on the window -> properties.